# Android “[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found”

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap-2.9.0

I copied xml folder from android/example/res/ and paste it into /res

Still i am getting following alert in emulator screen

```
“[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found”
```

See the screenshot

[image: emulator]

**Edit :**

my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current acceleration
    //
    function onSuccess(acceleration) {
        alert('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '\n' +
              'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '\n');
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the acceleration
    //
    function onError() {
        alert('onError!');
    }

    </script>




</head>
<body >
<center>
  <img src="img/full_logo.png">
</center>
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <input type=button value="Today" onClick="getdata('today');">
</div>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check my html code.

Comment: have you added cordova.js in your head tag to your starting(index.htm) html file?

Comment: Yes i have added cordova.js

Comment: Have you added the CordovaLib project to your project when you built the app? (How are you building?)

Comment: @QuickFix What is the uses of CordovaLib?

Comment: With older versions of Cordova/Phonegap the core functions were in a file named cordova.jar. With newer versions, those functions are now in a separate project name CordovaLib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have not add config.xml file in your project.Here what you should do..
1. Create a new folder name 'xml' in the res directory of your project
2. go to the lib/android/framework/res/xml directory of the Phonegap folder then copy the config.xml file to your project's xml folder.

I hope this will do for you

Comment: There is no `frameword` folder in `phonegap-2.9.0`

Comment: `framework` folder exist in PhoneGap version `2.9.1` But i am using `2.9.0` if i use `2.9.1` config.xml file it is working or not?

Comment: even the test app came from downloaded zip `phonegap-2.9.1` is not working,i think it has all requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you are using phonegap CLI from different machines, such as from MacOS and windows, you may see similar error. You need to remove and reinstall necessary plugins in current machine. For example, I had following error in my Windows 8 Machine.

```
11-06 06:05:52.410: W/System.err(989): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cordova.device.Device
11-06 06:05:52.420: W/System.err(989):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-06 06:05:52.430: W/System.err(989):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
11-06 06:05:52.430: W/System.err(989):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
11-06 06:05:52.430: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.getClassByName(PluginEntry.java:117)
11-06 06:05:52.430: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:93)
11-06 06:05:52.440: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:278)
11-06 06:05:52.440: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.execHelper(PluginManager.java:232)
11-06 06:05:52.440: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:227)
11-06 06:05:52.440: W/System.err(989):  at org.apache.cordova.ExposedJsApi.exec(ExposedJsApi.java:53)
11-06 06:05:52.440: W/System.err(989):  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
```

Use following commands to fix error for this case.

```
 phonegap local plugin remove org.apache.cordova.device
 phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

These commands change only following file plugins\org.apache.cordova.device.fetch.json.

```
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-{"source":{"type":"local","path":"/var/folders/v4/gn4xwpg91cgcmjc9psw86y7m0000gp/T/org.apache.cordova.device/package"}}
\ No newline at end of file
+{"source":{"type":"local","path":"C:\\Users\\ATILLA~1.OZG\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\org.apache.cordova.device\\package"}}
\ No newline at end of file
```

After that this error in my case, goes away.

Comment: I found that it wasn't enough to run these commands, I had to physically remove the `plugins` and `platforms` directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem; even after showing the error the app worked, including most of the plugins. But the plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" didn't work so I removed it from the project, then the 'initializing Cordova' error went away.
So something incompatible or at fault with the plugin, but don't know what as yet.
(Using Cordova 3.5 with Android)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the PluginManager class. Replace the below code (**phonegap v2.9.1**)

```
/**
 * Load plugins from res/xml/config.xml
 */
public void loadPlugins() {
    int id = this.ctx.getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("config", "xml", this.ctx.getActivity().getClass().getPackage().getName());
   ......
}
```

with

```
public void loadPlugins() {
        int id = this.ctx.getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("config", "xml",  this.ctx.getActivity().getPackageName());
    ........
}
```

You can find the plugin manager class in this package

> org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager