# Ionic Error initializing Cordova: Class not found

Tags: android, cordova, class, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i have a project ionic cordova, i make the build of the application using the commands "ionic build android", and he generated the folder "platform/android".I take this folder to the site "https://build.phonegap.com" and I order it to generate a apk. when i install this aplication through the apk, initializing the application, an error occurred (sorry for the english, I am Brazilian)

Print below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aAI4.png

how i fix?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to write a comment. [Did you try this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010704/android-error-error-initializing-cordova-class-not-found)

Comment: @WillyNelson Cordova and phonegap are two different flavours. I dont think you can take out the platform from cordova and build in phonegap

Comment: Did you find the solution?